# Stable Diffusion: Stacking the whole prompt into a variable

Tags: variables, artificial-intelligence

I ran across the problem with SD. I am looking for a way how to stack a longer prompt into a variable, so I can use it in a more elegant matter. Example given:

1. After a number of iterations we finally agree on something: blahblahblah is the way how I want to depict my object.
2. I want **blahblahblah = X**, so I can use it like "give me X with a cat," so the X is always the same.
3. Or, I could use an AI generator which would be able to edit existing image, e.g. to add a scientist, to make that scientist older etc. Basically, I miss the possibility of variables.
   [*FTIR spectrometer Nicolet iS50 with a cat* vs *FTIR spectrometer Nicolet iS50 with a butterfly*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijgpb.jpg)

I tried to slightly change the prompt to see the differences, I of course tried to google the solution or to search for a different AI engine and I tried to consult it wit a friend who works with AI.